# Bad operand types for binary operator

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I don't understand why `||` in the tenth line `while (one%6||one%17){` is considered **bad operand types for binary operator**. If someone could help me understand this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivisibleBy6or17 {
    public static void main(String[] args){             
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
        int one = in.nextInt();
        int sum=0;

        while (one%6||one%17){
            System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
            sum=+1;
        }
        System.out.print("Numbers read: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not C. You need to compare the result of modulo with 0.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, you have to have boolean values on both sides of `||`. And, neither `one % 6` nor `one % 17` are boolean. However, `one % 6 != 0` and `one % 17 != 0` are.